# Flexbox - 3 items in two rows

Tags: css, flexbox

I'd like to organise 3 items into two rows:

- first row - one item (which in fact is a two-column form, but that's
  sorted)
- second row - two items (text and button).

My aim is to make sure the second row items are vertically aligned to the sides of the table. I'm very limited as I'm using a form plugin and need to work with the divs I have.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please share some code and let us know where you got stuck, what you tried so far. Try reproducing it in https://jsbin.com or https://codepen.com

Answer (score 0):

I've actually solved it myself. I've noticed my plugin form had a class 'form columns', so I just had to use it.

Comment: Btw, I understand you may be irritated, but try to hold your horses. I'm a newbie here and perhaps didn't think of adding my code here straight away. Asking the right question and phrasing it in the correct way is a skill half of the success and sometimes have the impression experienced coders get really annoyed by wrongly phrased asks.